# Usage of the phrase, "when this" when referring to a condition

Tags: conditionals

Consider this statement.

The maximum number of solutions is given by the formula, x * x. For example, consider the case, x = 2, **when this maximum is 4.**

I thought there is a minor ambiguity in the above sentence with the phrase, "when this". I can intuitively get what is meant, is there any mistake or is any of the following formats better?

- For example, consider the case, x = 2, the maximum is 4.
- For example, when x = 2, the maximum is 4.

I want to know the correct usage of the phrase, "**when this**" used to refer a previous condition in the sentence.

Comment: when I read, "when this maximum is 4", I thought the sentence was in reverse order.  I don't see more than one meaning here.

Comment: "This" is essentially interchangeable with "the" here, except rather than just "the" it's "the thing I just mentioned." If you substitute "the," does the sentence make more sense?

Comment: You mean, replace "when this" by "the", then it makes sense.

Comment: "When this" is not a unit here, it's "when" and "this." The "when" is needed or else the meaning changes.

Comment: If I use "the" instead of "this", the sentence becomes. "For example, consider the case, x = 2, when the maximum is 4."  The substitution is not making the sentence in the form of a derivative, "if this, then that", the word when is confusing here. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you're missing something. The sentence is correct, and it's not of the form "if...then."

Comment: 'A when B' means that A and B are co-incident in time.  We sometimes use it to imply that B causes A.  In solving problems, the use of a formula can 'cause' a solution, so the example is backwards and slightly confusing.

Comment: "when x = 2, the maximum is 4" Is better and easier to understand.  The phrase  "consider the case" is pure noise and "when this" is awkward.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is grammatically correct as written. The primary source of the confusion is probably because of the "phrase" *x = 2*.

> ORIGINAL: The maximum number of solutions is given by the formula, x * x. For example, consider the case, x = 2, when this maximum is 4.

The first sentence introduces the idea that we are referring to a maximum. This is important only because it helps us understand that we are talking about a maximum, which helps us to understand the use of "this" in the subsequent sentence.

So let's look at the second sentence:

> ORIGINAL: For example, consider the case, x = 2, when this maximum is 4.
>
> SIMPLIFIED: Consider the case when this maximum is 4.

This is semantically essentially the same as "Consider the case when *the* maximum is 4"; the use of *this* just helps tie it back to the first sentence.

This sentence has a similar structure as the following (grammatical) sentences:

> The scenario ***where** that happens* is unlikely.
>
> I am interested in the time ***when** you were away*.
>
> Tell me about the scenario ***when** that happens*.

Your sentence is correct because you have an adjectival clause (*when this maximum is 4*) that modifies the noun *case*. The word *when* is needed to introduce the clause "*this maximum is 4*."